# Add class with [ngClass] depending on local html condition

Tags: html, css, angular, animation

I have used [ngClass] in the past, applying classes depending on the Boolean value of a variable held in the javascript/typescript before. However I am wondering if it is possible to apply it based on a local HTML boolean value or not?

ie.

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of data" #panel ngClass="{expanded: isExpanded}">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="itemName">Text</div>
    <div class="itemDir">Some more text</div>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!panel.isExpanded" (click)="panel.isExpanded=true">edit</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="panel.isExpanded" (click)="panel.isExpanded=false">cancel</mat-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, I am displaying one of two icons, depending on the local `isExpanded` variable defined within the HTML and not the backend.

I am wanting to apply a class based on this value... is it possible?

[Here is what I am working on](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expanding-card-singles)

Comment: what does `backend` mean? your `.ts`? You don't have `isExpanded` in your `.ts`?

Comment: `<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of data" #panel [ngClass]="{'expanded': isExpanded === true }">`

Comment: @xyz - That is correct. `isExpanded` is defined within the HTML

Comment: @Florian - Doesn't appear to be working for me :-(

Comment: I see what you need, I'm modifying your blitzz at the moment

Comment: Here is a hacky solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53635128 (based on @malbarmawi)

Comment: Here is a solution where you add property `expanded` to your items. https://stackblitz.com/edit/expanding-card-singles-p8h6v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like `[class.expanded]="isExpanded"`. binding to `class.expanded` trumps the class attribute

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of data" #panel [class.expanded]="panel.isExpanded" [class.notExpanded]="!panel.isExpanded">
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me...
Could you fork my blitz and post if it is working for you?

Comment: @physicsboy check https://stackblitz.com/edit/expanding-card-singles-fxhuju?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Hmm... I see that it can change the colour, but for some reason cannot change the height of the div? I put in a hardcoded starting size too, but still no change :-(

Comment: you miss the `px` at the end of the height.   `height: 300px ;`

Comment: OMG SUCH A NOOB MOVE ON MY PART! It actually works fine after adding that in XD
Apologies to everyone attempting to help me :-)

Comment: The only thing I find now is that the expansion happens instantly and not over a period of time as I thought `transition: all 2s;` would have done for me?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `*ngIf="true as isExpanded"` to make variable on the template

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4];"  >
  <div class="header" *ngIf="true as isExpanded" ngClass="{expanded: !isExpanded}">
    <div class="itemName">Text</div>
    <div class="itemDir">Some more text</div>
    <div *ngIf="isExpanded" (click)="isExpanded=!isExpanded">edit</div>
    <div *ngIf="!isExpanded" (click)="isExpanded=!isExpanded">cancel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53635128)

Comment: Doesn't appear to do anything from what I can see in your Blitz :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of data" #panel ngClass="{expanded: isExpanded}">
<div class="header">
    <div class="itemName">{{item.name}}</div>
    <div class="itemDir">{{item.directory}}</div>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!isExpanded;else other_content" (click)="isExpanded=true">edit</mat-icon>
    <ng-template #other_content>Other Icon goes here</ng-template>
</div>
```

You can refer the above code which use If and else by template referenced variable which properly toggle between both icon and non Icon